# Symlink to volume in Docker container

Tags: docker, symlink, mount

I've created a Docker container a small application, in which I have a directory whose contents I want to replace (or not) depending on the environment. I'm trying to solve this by creating a volume and only mounting it in other environments. Inside the container, I'm creating a symlink to the volume from my source directory.

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

# Copy in sources files etc
# Ensure the directory exists and make a symlink to it
RUN mkdir -p /data/share \
    && rm -rf /app/src/dir \
    && ln -s /data/share /app/src/dir \
    && chown -hR appropriate:settings /app/src/dir

VOLUME ["/data/share"]
```

When I run the container in development, I simply don't mount anything on `/data/share`, and in production I mount a directory from the host (which is in turn a mounted S3 directory, in case that makes a difference).

I'm finding that the `/data/share` directory is being correctly mounted, however my symlink simply fails to be established. Running `docker exec -it <container_id> ls -la /app/src/` does not show the directory as a symlink, nor does going inside the container by running bash and inspecting the directory. Creating the symlink by hand after the container has started is fine.

Do I need to do something different when creating symlinks during a container build and/or run?

**Update with specifics**

I'm attempting to mount a directory from the host (a mounted S3 bucket) in the container *only in production*, because I don't need it in dev & staging but I do need it to persist between containers and machines (I'm deploying through AWS Elastic Beanstalk) in production.

I've tried mounting the host directory directly on to `/app/src/dir/`, but I found I wasn't able to change the owner and group of the directory to allow the application to read from it (the web server doesn't run as root).

Comment: I seriously doubt you can create symlinks to volumes at build time. I expect it will work if you put the `ln -s` in a CMD or ENTRYPOINT script though.

Comment: In that case, would I be smarter to expose the source directory as a volume directly?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve tbh. I don't think you understand how volumes work: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/  http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/

Comment: Thanks for the links, they helped. I'm trying to mount an S3 bucket in a container. I'll update my question with some details.

Comment: Are you just asking how to set the permissions on the directory? That's fairly easy, something like `docker run -u root -v HOST_DIR:/tmp php:5.6-apache chown USER /tmp` should work.

Comment: Running a chown on the directory via docker run, docker exec and from inside the container all give me an error. I think this might actually be an issue with the host directory being a mounted S3 bucket using S3FS.

Comment: Ok, not sure about S3. I think you might want to open a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [s6-overlay](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay#init-stages) project which allows you to run initialization scripts on container start. Allowing you to mount a directory in s3 before launching your service. It also allows you to deinit a service on `docker stop` so you can inform any other services that a service is shutting down and reap any zombie processes.